# Example of non-abelian group with element have all order p prime?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, modules

I am searching for an example of a non-abelian group $G$, s.t. all elements in $G$ have order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number.
For $p=2$ such an example does not exist.

How did I come up with such a question? If $G$ is abelian with the property above, we can define a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space structure on $G$. And my proof used that $G$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So the above question arose naturally.

Comment: If $G$ is finite, then by Cauchy's theorem $G$ has order $p^n$.

Comment: See the [Discrete Heisenberg group mod $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p)

Comment: @ZPlaya Then, for finite $G$, it seems to be a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271386/non-abelian-finite-p-group-in-which-every-element-has-prime-order). I have overlooked this - sorry. By the way, also the case where all elements have (possibly different) prime orders is solved here. As an example consider the element orders of $A_5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is the following group, for an odd prime $p>2$:

$$G= \langle x, y, z  |   x^p=1,  y^p=1,  z^p=1,  [x,z]=1,  [y,z]=1,  [x,y]=z^{-1} \rangle$$
is non-abelian of order $p^3$, and all its non-trivial elements have order $p$.
The group is exactly the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

More generally, this question is related to the restricted Burnside problem:

**Proposition**: A finite group $G$ has the property that all non-trivial elements have the same order $p$ if and only if $p$ is prime and $G\ne 1$ is a quotient of $B_0(m,p)$ for some $m.$